# Deleting users information from multiple tables where user id is the foreign key with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, qsqlquery

```
use database

delete * 
from sys.foreign_keys 
where [Id] = '75C66316-8952-4E40-84C7-01BDD87B7FAD';
```

I'm very new to this level of complex SQL but, I'm trying to delete all of the user's information from all of the tables that use the user id as a key. I'm getting an error that reads "[id] is an invalid column name". Please let me know why this code doesn't work or what I could do better. thanks in advance.

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] 
WHERE [Id] = '75C66316-8952-4E40-84C7-01BDD87B7FAD';
```

This line would work but only if I could find a way to search each table that used that person's information.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish by `delete * from sys.foreign_keys` - but everything in the `sys` schema are system-only catalog view which you can **only** select from - you cannot manipulate them with `insert`, `update` or `delete`

Comment: Can you not use `ON DELETE CASCADE` on the FKs?

Comment: @marc_s honestly, I don't know what sys.foreign_keys did I was just hoping that find the child tables that use ID as the key.

Comment: @Charlieface I haven't tried that and I've never used it but ill look it up rn. Is there any way I can just test the ON DELETE CASCADE with a select instead of select?

Comment: Yes - that's exactly what `sys.foreign_keys` can tell you - what foreign key constraints a table has - but you can't just "delete" from that system catalog view to delete the data - you have to take the information you get, and then go to the foreign key tables and delete from those